# On the <permission> tag

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I'm reading the C# spec about `<permission>` tag with this syntax:

```
<permission cref="member">description</permission>
```

It is said that:

> This tag allows the security accessibility of a member to be
>   documented where `cref="member"` is the name of a member, while `description` is the description of the access to the member.

So I could argue that something like this could be valid:

```
/// <permission cref="foo">foo is not accessible</permission>
private void foo() {}
```

However in the spec there is the following example:

```
/// <permission cref="System.Security.PermissionSet">Everyone can 
/// access this method.</permission> 
public static void Test() { }
```

If `cref` is the member that must be documented for the accessibility what does `System.Security.PermissionSet` do with it?

Really I don't understand the spec example!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* that was designed to document code access security requirements of a given method\class. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Do stuff
/// </summary>
/// <permission cref="PermissionSet">Caller should have full trust</permission>
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]        
public void DoStuff() {

}
```

Here we demand full trust permission set, and we state that explicitly in documentation of our method. Also consider this:

```
/// <summary>
///  Do stuff 2
/// </summary>
/// <permission cref="FileIOPermission">Caller should have unrestricted IO access</permission>
[FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted = true)]
public void DoStuff2() {

}
```

Here we demand specific `FileIOPermission` (not permission set), and so we state that explicitly in documentation.

This is certainly not to document accessibility (public\private) of a member - why do that at all? Accessibility is part of function\class definition and do not need to be documented.